# How to print this pattern in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL server and started solve some question, but not sure how to print triangle in sql

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: This EXACT question has been asked and answered many times. Try searching first before posting. You won't learn anything if someone gives you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can use while loop to iterate and replicate to print * mutiple times, try this

```
DECLARE @i INT = 5

WHILE(@i>0)
BEGIN
   PRINT REPLICATE('* ', @i);
   SET @i = @i - 1;
END
```